# Which is best for a list of points: an array of point structs or a 2 dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I need an array where each  member has 3 elements of the same type. I can use an array of structs, or a 2 dimensional array.

```
// Array of structs:
struct point {  double x, y, z; };
struct point path[20000];  
// Now access z by
path[i].z
```

```
// 2-dimensional array:
double path[20000][3];
// Access z by
path[i][2]
```

Which method is most efficient? Or are they the same?

Comment: Efficiency is really hard to talk about in the abstract, because different approaches, and different trade-offs. In this case, they're about the same, but the named `x`/`y`/`z` fields read way better. Plus, the `Point` abstraction is just really useful overall

Comment: That's not a two-dimensional array. [What are the differences between a multidimensional array and an array of arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays)

Comment: I'd venture to suggest that, unless you're trying to save bytes or microseconds, you should use the version that has most expressive power. Someone has to maintain this stuff, after all.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference.

If I remember correctly, in theory a compiler is allowed to insert padding bytes between the members of `struct point`, but no sane compiler would do it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`struct point {  double x, y, z; };` may incur padding - although quite unlikely.
`double path[20000][3];` has no padding.

In this case, I recommend to code for clarity.
Since the comment hints that the access is of `z`, use `.z` rather than `[2]`

```
// Now access z by
path[i].z
```